# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have the below JDBC code:

```
public int addItem(String name, String price, String count, String isPR, String img) {
    int result = 0;
    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO T001_ITEM"
                + "(ITEM_NO,ITEM_NM,UNIT_PRICE,STOCK_COUNT,RECORD_DATE,IS_PR,ITEM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH)"
                + "VALUES(TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'" + name + "','" + price + "','" + count + "', sysdate,'" + isPR
                + "','" + img + "')";

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        result = pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

It throws the below error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you Google ORA-01722?  This is an error code that has a specific meaning.  If you look it up, maybe that will help narrow down your problem.  As it stands, your question has too much code and too little information for us to help you.

Comment: Concatenation of Strings to build your insert SQL exposes you to SQL Injections.  BTW, what problem are you facing?

Comment: Why are you passing all the arguments as strings? Use the right data types. At the moment it could be many things, but one possibility is that implicit conversion of a string (e.g. price) is tripping over implicit conversion because your session NLS settings don't match the string format (comma vs. period as decimal separator). But as you've given no information that's just a guess, clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Do not concatenate your values into your query like you do now with `'" + name + "'`, and to avoid SQL injection, I suggest you use a prepared statement with parameters:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO T001_ITEM "
        + "(ITEM_NO, ITEM_NM, UNIT_PRICE, STOCK_COUNT, RECORD_DATE, IS_PR, ITEM_IMAGE_FILE_PATH) "
        + "VALUES(TABLE_SEQ.NEXTVAL, ?, ?, ?, sysdate, ?, ?)";
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, name);
pstmt.setString(2, price);
pstmt.setString(3, count);
pstmt.setString(4, isPR);
pstmt.setString(5, img);
```

**Note**

Make sure the type of your attributes is same in your table, you set all your values as String. I don't think that the `price` can be a String or `isPR` seems to be a `Boolean` not a `String`, and the `count` can be a number not a `String` so check your types carefully.

If you can't change the type outside your method then you can **cast** it to the right type but **you should to test them**, this can make another problem.

So for example

```
int countN = Integer.parseInt(count);
```

or

```
pstmt.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(count));
```

and so on for all the other type.

Like what this [documentation says here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01722) :

> **What causes this error?**
>
> An ORA-01722 ("invalid number") error occurs when an attempt is made
>   to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be
>   converted into a valid number. Valid numbers contain the digits '0'
>   through '9', with possibly one decimal point, a sign (+ or -) at the
>   beginning or end of the string, or an 'E' or 'e' (if it is a floating
>   point number in scientific notation). All other characters are
>   forbidden.

So like I said before, check if the type is exact in your table, you can't set a String in the place of `Number`

You can learn more about this error [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01722.php) and [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01722_invalid_number.html)

Comment: Could you include an explicit comment as to what causes the problem, because you are presenting a solution, but you depend on those links for explaining the problem. It would greatly improve your answer if you'd add a short explanation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and what about now? it seems clear or should i make more explanation

Comment: Looks good now. Technically JDBC does allow you to call `setString` on a numerical type, as long as the string is convertible it will work. So parsing/casting yourself is technically not necessary, but it will make it easier to find the problem (and to handle difference in the format, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i don't have enough reputations to add this as comment,

ORA-01722: Simply means it is unable to convert the String values to the integer.

By looking at your what i can understand is you are passing price and count as string to the DB, can you check what is the declaration of the fields in DB. You need to convert them to int and then you can try insertion.